# Decompose a power of the radius as a sum of squares of forms

Tags: polynomials

I am interested in a decomposition
$$(x_1^2+...+ x_n^2)^d=\sum_{i=1}^m (P_i(x_1,\dots,x_n))^2$$
where $d>1$ is odd, $m\leq n$, $P_i$ are forms of degree $d$.
Of course, the greatest common divisor for all $P_i$ is 1,
to prevent the trivial decomposition with $P_i=x_i(x_1^2+...+ x_n^2)^{(d-1)/2}$.